# Using clicks and keys for different events on Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, function, matplotlib, events

I want to use the mouse clicks to draw lines, while a letter button on the keyboard to draw a point on a Matplotlib figure. This is the code I have so far.

```
def onclick(event):
    global current_coords
    if event.inaxes:
        current_coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if len(current_coords) == 2:
            ax.plot([current_coords[0][0], current_coords[1][0]],
                    [current_coords[0][1], current_coords[1][1]], 'ro-')
            coords.append([current_coords[0], current_coords[1]])
            current_coords[:] = []

        fig.canvas.draw()
        
def onkey(event):
    global current_coords1
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        current_coords1.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if len(current_coords1) == 1:
            ax.plot([current_coords1[0][0], current_coords1[1][0]], 'bo-')
            coords1.append([current_coords1[0], current_coords1[1]])
            current_coords1[:] = []

        fig.canvas.draw()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
cid1 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onkey)
plt.show()
```

The first function should create a line when you click twice on the figure. The second should just create a dot when you press "P" on the figure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this complete code? although matplotlib expert know what you mean, you are still encouraged to provide complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I changed the key form `p` to `x` for drawing points as `p` is also the shortcut to *pan* the graph.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# %matplotlib widget  # for jupyter notebooks (pip install ipympl)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

global current_coords
current_coords = []

def onclick(event):
    global current_coords
    if event.inaxes:
        current_coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if len(current_coords) == 2:
            ax.plot([current_coords[0][0], current_coords[1][0]],
                    [current_coords[0][1], current_coords[1][1]], 'ro-')
            current_coords[:] = []
    fig.canvas.draw()

def onkey(event):
    print(event.key)
    if event.key == 'x':
        if event.xdata is not None and event.ydata is not None:
            ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, 'bo-')
            fig.canvas.draw()


cid1 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
cid2 = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onkey)
```

Comment: Sorry this solution actually does not work. I am using %matplotlib notebook and when I press the letter nothing happens. Do you know what would be causing this issue?

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook so I have '%matplotlib notebook'. Does '%matplotlib widget' work with Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: I'm getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipympl'. But I did pip install ipympl and it is already installed.

Comment: Yep, I only have one environment

Comment: I tried it with Spyder but still no joy unfortunately

Comment: Apologies. The code runs and the figure is produced. The functionality to create the lines using the mouse is working fine, but the functionality to use the letter x to draw a point does not work. Nothing happens when I press x or any other letter that I tested.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still unresponsive. Is it possible to add a button beside the graph, and if this is pressed it determines what the click does on the graph. EG. If I press a "Red" button, it produces a red dot when I click the graph, when I press a "Blue" button it produces a blue dot when I click the graph

Comment: But do you get something printed on your console if you press a button? 
Yes this is possible and there are examples on the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/radio_buttons.html#sphx-glr-gallery-widgets-radio-buttons-py)

Comment: Oh it's working now actually. I forgot to change 'key_press_event'. Thanks for fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the accepted answer do not commented, but please notice that the function 'button_press_event' is changed to 'key_press_event'. matplotlib need to know from where are you expecting each input